# animate wont .stop() - annoyingly simple Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am new to Jquery and I am trying to get a search field to animate in and then when you click the close icon (#search-close) it animates out and the #search-close button disappears.

animating in works fine but when I click the close button it animates out but immediately animates in again

I know this is really simple

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

$j(document).ready(function() {

$j('#search-slide').mousedown(function() {
$j('#search-close').fadeIn(100);
$j('#search-slide').animate({'left':-1});
$j('#tbcopy a').fadeOut(100);});

$j('#search-close').mousedown(function() {
$j('#search-close').stop().hide();
$j('#search-slide').stop().animate({'left':-250});
});});


</script>
```

Comment: I hope you understand that [`mousedown()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) also catch when you click-n-drag. If you don't want this behavior you must use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error, I believe, is due to where the close button is, since it is within the top div, you actually trigger both click events. The reason your stop() doesn't work is probably because these have different animation queues since they're distinct elements. Try added a boolean value to the outer div that is checked before the animation is done on it.

Answer (score 3):

Add `.stop(true,true)` this will set clearqueu to true and jump to end of animation.

Comment: @user2595800 could you set it in a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the .finish() method as it is similar to .stop(true,true), but .finish() will actually finish the animation and not stop it in the middle.

Comment: no doesnt work either - I have set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maxl23/wTTqq/1/

Comment: This is expected behaviour the way you use your code. You are triggering both functions on mousedown and you never check if the box is "open" or not. You can use a flag to keep track if the box is open or not and then perform the functionality you want. Same idea as Braiam suggested. And why are you using mousdown and not simple click events? I have edited the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maxl23/wTTqq/1/

Answer (score -1):

You could add a class that would prevent the box from being triggered again after clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-slide').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('visible')) {
            console.log('triggered');
            return;
        } else {
            $('#search-close').fadeIn(100);
            $(this).animate({
                'left': -1
            }).addClass('visible');
            $('#tbcopy a').fadeOut(100);
        }
    });
    $('#search-close').click(function () {
        $(this).stop().hide();
        $('#search-slide').stop().animate({
            'left': -250
        });
    });
});
```

A working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTTqq/16/). Just as note, the box won't open again with my solution, but as you didn't specified you wanted it to open again.